# How come /bin/rm -rf /backups/hourly.5/ takes forever on a backup server?

Tags: centos, backup, ext3, rsnapshot

They're simply hardlinks so the files shouldn't actually even be deleted.

What options do I have? It even seems to take quite some load. I don't see how deleting 30.000 hard-links should take more than a minute, let alone a full hour.

I use rsnapshot,  centos and an ext3 file system.

Comment: I am also a rsnapshot user and deletes can take a looong time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete all those files it must traverse the directory tree, and go down into the whole lot, deleting each files & directory one by one. This can take a while.

Sometimes the choice of filesystem can matter. Some filesystems can take a long time to delete lots of little files, some are good at this.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the `dir_index` feature is not enabled for the filesystem. Using `debugfs` will allow you to verify if enabled and set it if not.

Comment: `tune2fs` may be a more appropriate tool for end-users than `debugfs`.